# How to apply transition only to a label not the whole view swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition

I feel like this is a dum question, but I can't find a solution. I've got a collection view, each cell has a different background color and when the user scrolls through the collection I change the labels textColor to match the background color of the cell currently in view. The label is outside of the collection view.

The detection of which cell is in view and changing the color works and I now want to apply a transition effect to the labels textColor so that it looks nicer when the user scrolls. Only problem is that my transition animation is also interacting with the scrolling animation on the collection view which looks very weird.

Is there a way to target my transition so that it only applies to the labels text color? Or maybe I need to change the way I'm detecting which cell is in view and how that triggers the animation.

Anyway my current code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var balanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var overviewCollection: UICollectionView!

func configureVisibleIndexPath() {
    let visibleCells = overviewCollection.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    visibleCells.forEach {
        indexPath in
        if let cell = overviewCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath), overviewCollection.bounds.contains(cell.frame) {
            print("visible row is \(indexPath.row)")
            
            let visibleIndexPath = indexPath.row
            
            switch visibleIndexPath {
            case 0:
                UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations:  {
                    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywGreen")
                })
            case 1:
                UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywYellow")
                })
            case 2:
                UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywBlue")
                })
            case 3:
                UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywWhite")
                })
            default:
                UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywGreen")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `with:` parameter from `view` to `self.balanceLabel`.

Instead of this:

```
UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywGreen")
})
```

do this:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.balanceLabel, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "ywGreen")
})
```

Comment: Thank you, knew there was a simple solution and I was asking a dum question